# How to log a variable within a namespace (works elsewhere in Silverstripe)

Tags: php, silverstripe

With a Silverstripe site, how do I log within a namespace or within a class under the vendor folder?

e.g. `SS_Log::log(print_r($variable, true), SS_Log::NOTICE);`

Have tried using a backslash `\SS_Log::log(print_r($variable, true), \SS_Log::NOTICE);`

Logging works fine outside a namespaced class/vendor folder, so this is not a config setting issue.

Do I need a `use` statement? Any advice please?

**Update**
Thank you for your comments.  You are right `\SS_Log::log(print_r($variable, true), \SS_Log::NOTICE);` works within a namespace in the vendor folder.  My mistake, I wasn't calling the correct function; hence the lack of logs appearing.

Comment: Backslash should be enough. Didn't that work? Maybe you need to explicitly "require" the classes?

Comment: Looks fine - what is the error you receive?

Comment: Might be a silly question, but the class you're logging *from* is loaded via SilverStripe's framework right? You're not initiating it directly through the composer autoloader?

Comment: @RobbieAverill The class I needed to log from was within the vendor folder and was accessed through the composer autoloader.  It was not located within a Silverstripe module, however, the module accessed the class via a `use` statement.  The backslash did the trick with \SS_Log, as it does also with \Debug::show($variable).  Thanks.